# The injection point has the following annotations

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

i have one pb, i can't find the solution because i think that i have more than one pb related in my project :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-22 14:28:12.551 ERROR 6272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field connexionRepository in com.example.demo.service.UserConnexionService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserConnexionRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserConnexionRepository' in your configuration.
```

My class which is concerned is :

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.dao.UserConnexionRepository;
import com.example.demo.entities.UserConnexion;

@Transactional
@Service
public class UserConnexionService implements IUserService {
        @Autowired(required = true)
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired(required = true)
        private UserConnexionRepository connexionRepository;    
        
        
        
        @Autowired(required = true)
        @Qualifier("connexionRepositoryService")
        public void setConnexionRepository(UserConnexionRepository connexionRepository) {
            this.connexionRepository = connexionRepository;
        }

        public UserConnexion modifyVente(int id, UserConnexion user) {
            user.setId(id);
            return connexionRepository.save(user);
            
        }

        public UserConnexion saveNewUser(UserConnexion user) {
            String hashPW =bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
            user.setPassword(hashPW);
            return connexionRepository.save(user);
            
        }

        public void deleteUser(int id) {
            
            connexionRepository.deleteUser(id);
            
        }

        @Override
        public UserConnexion getUser(String identifiant, String password) {
            UserConnexion user = connexionRepository.findUser(identifiant, password);
            
            if(user==null){
                throw new RuntimeException("user introuvable !");
            }
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public List<UserConnexion> getUserByMC(String mot) {
            List<UserConnexion> user = connexionRepository.findUserByMC(mot);
    
            if(user==null){
                throw new RuntimeException("user introuvable !");
            }
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public UserConnexion findUserByIdentifiant(String identifiant) {
            UserConnexion user = connexionRepository.findUserByIdentifiant(identifiant);
            return user;
        }

}
```

And the call of this one is here :

package com.example.demo.dao;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.entities.UserConnexion;


public interface UserConnexionRepository extends JpaRepository<UserConnexion, Long> {   
    
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM user", nativeQuery = true)
    public UserConnexion findUser(@Param("username")String username, @Param("password")String password);
    
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM user u where u.identifiant LIKE :login", nativeQuery = true)
    public UserConnexion findUserByIdentifiant(@Param("login")String login);
    
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM user u where u.nom LIKE %:mot% OR u.prenom LIKE %:mot%", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<UserConnexion> findUserByMC(@Param("mot")String mot);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="DELETE FROM user WHERE user.id= :id", nativeQuery = true)
    public void deleteUser(@Param("id")int id);
    
}
```

someone can help me? i can give you the link to git repository also to see all the project.
Thank you

Comment: Have you activated Jpa repository support in your spring config?

Comment: Can you share your main class and the package that it is in?

Comment: tgdavies, how can i do this? and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need both:

```
 @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserConnexionRepository connexionRepository;    
    
    
    
    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("connexionRepositoryService")
    public void setConnexionRepository(UserConnexionRepository connexionRepository) {
        this.connexionRepository = connexionRepository;
    }
```

just add :

```
@Autowired
private UserConnexionRepository connexionRepository;
```

Comment: Or, even better, use constructor injection and make the field final.

Comment: thanks Andy and Shamitha, i have already tried only @Autowired
private UserConnexionRepository connexionRepository; how can i add constructor injection? i have to add an empty constructor in UserConnexionRepository?

Comment: @Ghassen, it's like you did as a setter method above, only change is it's the constructor. If the answer worked for you, you can accept the answer, so in the future you would get more chances on getting answers